# use tensorflow to get value from a value tensor by index tensor

Tags: tensorflow

There is a index tensor like this: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`   (shape is batch * length)

and there is a value tensor like this: (shape is  batch * length * deep)

```
[[[0.9,0.9,0.1,0.1],[0.9,0.1,0.8,0.1],[0.9,0.1,0.1,0.6]],
[[0.1,0.9,0.8,1],[1,2,0.8,0.1],[0.1,0.1,2,0.6]]].
```

how can I get `[[0.9,0.8,0.6],[0.9,0.8,0.6]]` with tensorflow?

Comment: `tf.math.reduce_max(tensor, axis=-1)`?

Comment: The problem I had was taking a row of values and using it as an index in the last dimension of another matrix, corresponding values. It's not about the maximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best solution, but it works: `tf.gather_nd(values, tf.expand_dims(index, -1), batch_dims=2)`

e.g.:

```
>>> index = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> values = tf.constant([[[0.9,0.9,0.1,0.1],[0.9,0.1,0.8,0.1],[0.9,0.1,0.1,0.6]],[[0.1,0.9,0.8,1],[1,2,0.8,0.1],[0.1,0.1,2,0.6]]])
>>> result = tf.gather_nd(values, tf.expand_dims(index, -1), batch_dims=2)
>>> result.eval()
array([[0.9, 0.8, 0.6],
       [0.9, 0.8, 0.6]], dtype=float32)
```